# Newbie on producing, needing some tips?

Tags: producer, newbie

Hi, my friends. let me explain my problem (please do not pay atention in my english, i don't speak very well)

i'm a dj and starting to produce house music, but, the videos or the "tip videos" are more pratical and i need some basic knowledge, starting from the begining: what its a compressor, what is a wave form, oscilators, wahtever, audio basics.

Can you, guys, introduce me some books, videos that can help me to start being a real professional producer? i want do study before starting to produce.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Find a book by Bob Katz called, "*Mastering Audio*".
"*Master Handbook of Acoustics*" is another great resource though longer.
You get through both of those and you'll have a head full of science.

http://www.pdfmagazines.org/tutorials/34579-master-handbook-of-acoustics.html

Go to the download via novafile, do the 'slow' free download - they almost hide the button but it's at the bottom of the Free column. I am not associated with novafile.com haha.

Go forth and science my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can still enroll in these Coursera classes and check out the videos:
https://class.coursera.org/digitalsounddesign-001/class/index
https://class.coursera.org/musicproduction-001/class/index

Answer (score 0):

Hi João,

This is a Sound Design forum. You'll probably have better luck finding tips on house music production on a Music forum, like [IDM Forums](http://www.idmforums.com) or [Subsekt](http://www.subsekt.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Hi there,

Being the wonderous age of the internet, there are loads of videos in assorted languages that can fully explain your queries as well as the above mentioned books and links.